# Database Schema Recommendation

Tags: database, database-design, schema

I am having a brain-cease on a data problem that I am in need of modeling.  I will do my best to outline the tables, and relationships

```
users (basic user information name/etc)
users.id

hospitals (basic information about hospital name/etc)
hospitals.id

pages
pages.id
user_id (page can be affiliated with a user)
hospital_id (page can be affiliated with a hospital)
```

Here is where the new data begins, and I am having an issue

```
groups (name of a group of pages)
groups.id

groups_pages (linking table)
group_id
page_id
```

Now here is the tricky part .. a group can be 'owned' by either a user or hospital, but those pages arent necessarily affiliated with that user/hospital .. In addition, there is another type of entity (company) that can 'own' the group

When displaying the group, I will need to know of what type (user / hospital / company) the group is and be able to get the correct affiliated data (name, address, etc)

Im drawing a blank on how to link groups to its respective owner, knowing that its respective owner can be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Party` is a generic term for person or organization.
- Keep all common fields (phone no, address..) in the `Party` table.
- `Person` and `Hospital` should have only specific fields for the sub-type.
- If the **company** has different set of columns from `Hospital` simply add it as another subtype.
- If `Hospital` and **company** have same columns, rename the `Hospital` to more generic `Organization`
- `PartyType` is the discriminator `{P,H}`

[image]

Comment: this is pretty similar to where I landed - esp. with naming hospitals/etc to a more generic term of organizations

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use some form of discriminator.  Like adding a column with "owner_type", you could then use either an enum, a vchar, or just an int to represent what type of owner the column represents.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server) is a good tutorial on how to model inheritance in a database while maintaining a reasonable normal form and referential integrity.

Condensed version for you:  Create another table, `owners`, and let it keep a minimal set of attributes (what users and hospitals have in common, maybe a full name, address, and of course an `id`).  Users and hospitals will have their respective `id` columns that will simultaneously be their primary keys and also foreign keys referencing `users.id`.  Give users the attributes that hospital's don't have and vice versa.  Now each hospital is represented by two easily joined rows, one from `owners` and one from `hospitals`.

This allows you to reference `users.id` from `groups.owner_id`.

(There is also a simpler alternative where you create just one table for users and hospitals and put NULLs to all columns that do not apply to a particular row, but that quickly gets unwieldy.)

Answer (score 0):

```
HospitalGroups(HospitalID, GroupID)
UserGroups(UserID, GroupID)
CompanyGroups(CompanyID, GroupID)

Groups(GroupID,....)

GroupPages(GroupID, PageID)

Pages(PageID, ...)
```

Would be the classic way.

The discriminator idea mentioned by @Robert would also work, but you lose referential integrity, so you need more code instead of more tables.

Comment: with the multiple group linking tables .. When selecting everythig from groups, how does one know if additional data is in the hospital/user/or company table?

Comment: Additional data about what? If it's about pages or groups, then it shouldn't be in those tables.